# Fly-by vs flow-through DMA

Tags: microcontroller, dma

I know that fly by DMA controllers (such as Intel 8257) are basically rewiring the circuit and arbitrating the flow of data.

On the other hand the flow through ones keep some of the data into its internal buffer (such as the one in STM32F4 controller).

I wonder which of these techniques for implementing a DMA controller is better, why and which is used nowadays?

In my opinion it is better to just rewire the circuit and control how the data flows directly on the bus, even though if the DMA controller is faster in transferring the data it would be better to first buffer the data and then send it.

Comment: "better" is a subjective word.

Comment: I would like to get an answer which will convince me which of these 2 is better, or at least explain in which situation should they be used.